# Do soldiers in Attack on Titan have different ODM gear or is it custom made for them?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Historia is 4'7 so in other words, she is short. On the other hand, we have Mike Zacharias who is 6'5. Do they have the same size gear or is it custom made for them?

Answer (score 2):

Back during the Female Titan arc, Armin recognizes that Annie was using Marco's ODM gear. So at the very least, they are unique enough to be told apart if you are familiar with them.

Then again, most of the fitting of the ODM gear is done through leather straps, so it's not like you would need much customization to tailor it to each soldier.

Comment: Armin said that because it has scratches on it.

Comment: Isn't it because it was damaged and Marco was fixing it rather than it was customized for each one of them beforehand? Armin recognized it because he was watching Marco perform maintenance on his own gear and he could tell where Marco fixed it. They perform maintenance on their own equipment so I guess they're the ones who do all the adjusting, like in Chapter 31. The equipment is not custom made for each of them.

Comment: you should have put this as an answer, but it works regardless, it works

Comment: but the metal parts not the straps, do they adjust that depending on size?